# DropdownList Similar to Gmail

Tags: asp.net

I have a normal `DropDownList`. I wanted to make it look like Gmail Dropdowns like which appears in gmail chat set status here section.

Can anyone help me with that ?

Comment: In general the stack community doesn't do things for you they help you to do them yourself, Have a peek at http://whathaveyoutried.com and let us know what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

There are many third party free jQuery plugins that you can use. 
Try twitter bootstrap [button groups](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonGroups).

Answer (score 0):

possible you can find your answer in this question

**http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327643/how-to-do-drop-down-box-like-more-action-in-gmail**